# How to set the time for the screen to lock asking for the password?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, time, screensaver

I can set the inactivity time for the screen saver to start, but I cannot set the time for the screen to lock asking for the password.

Is it possible to do it? Is it possible to synchronize the two?

Comment: This computer on a domain?

Comment: Yes. It is a company network.

Comment: Unless you are an Administrator on the domain itself you won't be able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly true, you are assuming the domain is managed fully. If the GPO has not been set-up for screensaver, by which I mean not configured you can go into Screen Saver settings and check the 'On resume, display logon screen' box. You need to use a mix of screen saver time and screen sleep if you want the screen to turn off a time period before the machine locks itself.

Answer (score 1):

As [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) partially pointed out in the comments to the question, this is most likely controlled by a group policy (GPO, group policy object) on the network, and you thus will not be able to change it without domain administrator access. (You *could* have the privileges required to change it without having all-out domain admin access, but that is even more unlikely. And either way, you should then be able to change it normally through the UI.)

Contact your company's IT support department or equivalent if you want to pursue this. Especially if the company is of any reasonable size, however, it is fairly likely that the answer you will get is "sorry, same for everyone, no exceptions, live with it".